# How to show a column in Excel Export in a ZFDATAGRID and hide the same column in the GRID display?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zfdatagrid

I have a column 'ID' in my grid, i am hiding that column from the data grid using 
`$grid->setColumnsHidden(array('id'));`

But I need that 'ID' column in my report, I am doing an excel export using 
`$grid->setExport(array('excel'));`

Is it possible to do that?? If so please help me out here...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isExport()` method of the grid to hide the ID Field only if this is not an export:

```
if(!$grid->isExport()){
    $grid->setColumnsHidden(array('id'));
}
```